# Generalize Lagrange multiplier method to function space (Linear Algebra in function space)

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, orthogonality

I want to prove following conjecture. (I'm not sure it is true or not) (It is required to prove isoperimetric problem)

$
Let \ f,g_1,\ldots, g_n, \eta \in \mathbb R ^{[a,b]}, W = \{g_1, \ldots, g_n\}\\
Define \ \langle f,g \rangle=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx
$

The conjecture:
$
\left( \eta \text{ is orthogonal to } W \Rightarrow \langle \eta, f\rangle =0\right) \Rightarrow f \in Span \ \{g_1, \ldots, g_n \} 
$

The following proof is not completed.

$
W^\bot \subset \{f\}^\bot\\
\left(W\cup \{f\}\right)^\bot=W^\bot\\
\left(W\cup \{f\}\right)^{\bot\bot}=W^{\bot\bot}
$

If $\forall W\in V \ (\ W^{\bot\bot} = Span \ W$), then the theorem will be true. But this is true if the vector space has finite dimension. Is that property still true in $\mathbb R^{[a,b]}$? or, Is there any other way to prove?

Comment: Where do you see the connection to generalzed Lagrange multipliers?

Answer (score 0):

Since $W$ is finite-dimensional, it is a closed subspace, hence $W^{\perp\perp}=W$. The underlying Hilbert space is $L^2(a,b)$.